# Cut copy paste option are not visible for CustomEditText in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I have implemented one custom edit text widget based on my requirement. I am just setting drawables and custom font in EditText field.

When I perform Long press on the text, i am not getting option to edit the text with Cut, Copy, Paste option? How can i enable it? Below is my element attributes.

```
<CustomEditText
            android:id="@+id/customEditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:background="@color/blackColor"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:hint="@string/customHintMessage"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine|textLongMessage"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textColor="@color/lightWhiteColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/editText_font_size"
            app:typeface="@string/regularFont" >
</customEditText>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
android:longClickable="true"
```